# Why does this message print extra times (more than I want it to print)?

Tags: java, recursion, infinite

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Math;

public class War {
    ArrayList deck = new ArrayList(0);
    ArrayList player1 = new ArrayList(0);
    ArrayList player2 = new ArrayList(0);
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int count = 0;

private void setup ()
{
    for (int x = 1; x <= 13; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= 4; y++)
        {
            deck.add(x);
        }
    }

    while (deck.size() > 26)
    {
        double x = Math.random() * deck.size();
        int y = (int) x;

        player1.add(deck.remove(y));
    }

    while (deck.size() > 0)
    {
        double x = Math.random() * deck.size();
        int y = (int) x;

        player2.add(deck.remove(y));
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++)
    {
        sum1 += (int) player1.get(x);
        sum2 += (int) player2.get(x);
    }

    System.out.println("Player 1's starting power is " + sum1 + ".");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Player 2's starting power is " + sum2 + ".");
    System.out.println();

    if (sum1 == sum2)
    {
        System.out.println("The two player's starting powers are equal! This'll be a good one, folks!");
    }
}

public void play ()
{
    if (hasSomeoneWon() || count == 0)
    {
        setup();
    }

    while (!player1.isEmpty() && !player2.isEmpty())
    {
        int a = (int) player1.get(0);
        int b = (int) player2.get(0);

        if (a > b)
        {
            player1.add(player1.remove(0)); // The winner's card is re-added to his deck before
            player1.add(player2.remove(0)); // the loser's is added to the winner's deck.
        }

        if (a < b)
        {
            player2.add(player2.remove(0));
            player2.add(player1.remove(0));
        }

        if (a == b)
        {
            war();
        }
    }

    victory();
}

private void war ()
{
    ArrayList temp1 = new ArrayList(0);
    ArrayList temp2 = new ArrayList(0);
    temp1.add(player1.remove(0));
    temp2.add(player2.remove(0));
    int x = 0;

    while (!(player1.isEmpty() || player2.isEmpty()) && x < 3)
    {
        temp1.add(player1.remove(0));
        temp2.add(player2.remove(0));
        x++;
    }

    int a = (int) temp1.get(temp1.size() - 1);
    int b = (int) temp2.get(temp2.size() - 1);

    if (a == b)
    {
        if (temp1.size() != temp2.size())
        {
            if (temp1.size() > temp2.size())
            {
                while (!temp1.isEmpty())
                {
                    player1.add(temp1.remove(0));
                }

                while (!temp2.isEmpty())
                {
                    player1.add(temp2.remove(0));
                }
            }

            else
            {
                while (!temp2.isEmpty())
                {
                    player2.add(temp2.remove(0));
                }

                while (!temp1.isEmpty())
                {
                    player2.add(temp1.remove(0));
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (player1.isEmpty() || player2.isEmpty())
            {
                if (player1.isEmpty())
                {
                    while (!temp2.isEmpty())
                    {
                        player2.add(temp2.remove(0));
                    }

                    while (!temp1.isEmpty())
                    {
                        player2.add(temp1.remove(0));
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    while (!temp1.isEmpty())
                    {
                        player1.add(temp1.remove(0));
                    }

                    while (!temp2.isEmpty())
                    {
                        player1.add(temp2.remove(0));
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                war();
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            while (!temp1.isEmpty())
            {
                player1.add(temp1.remove(0));
            }

            while (!temp2.isEmpty())
            {
                player1.add(temp2.remove(0));
            }
        }

        else
        {
            while (!temp2.isEmpty())
            {
                player2.add(temp2.remove(0));
            }

            while (!temp1.isEmpty())
            {
                player2.add(temp1.remove(0));
            }
        }

        play();
    }
}

private void victory ()
{
    if (player1.isEmpty() && sum2 > sum1)
    {
        System.out.println("Player 2 has won!");
    }

    if (player1.isEmpty() && sum1 > sum2)
    {
        System.out.println("Upset! Player 2 has won!");
    }

    if (player2.isEmpty() && sum1 > sum2)
    {
        System.out.println("Player 1 has won!");
    }

    if (player2.isEmpty() && sum2 > sum1)
    {
        System.out.println("Upset! Player 1 has won!");
    }

    hasSomeoneWon();
}

private boolean hasSomeoneWon ()
{
    if (player1.isEmpty() || player2.isEmpty())
    {
        count++;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Sorry for including all of my code, but I don't know which part is causing the extra printing.

This is the card game War. It's supposed to play out the game between two players on its own and then print the winner. Whenever I've played it, though, the victory message (whichever one gets printed) is printed a variable number of times. I'm guessing this has something to do with either where and how often I've included my calls to some of the methods OR the recursive call to war within the war() method.

My only experience with Java is an AP Computer Science class I took this school year, so I'm for sure a noob by the standards of everyone reading this.

Comment: It helps to know what it is repeatedly printing...

Comment: Please include the code you use to invoke the game.

Comment: I thought it would be clear from my explanation, but apparently, it is not to everyone. The printed messages to which I alluded are found in the victory method.

Comment: What do you mean, cheeken? There is no other code involved here. The class's entire code is copied into the question.

Comment: Post what prints out exactly. That would be most helpful. Especially the unexpected printing. I also find it interesting that `hasSomeoneWon()` is called but the result is not actually used.

Comment: Output: http://cache.gyazo.com/33c08e92a6503fbc46a991199ecc8373.png

Comment: mjb162, that's because that boolean method also increase by 1 the variable "count," which is used (admittedly uselessly, now that I think about it) to keep track of if the game has finished. If it is not 0, then a new game should be set up. I should add a "count = 0" to the setup method, probably.

Comment: Another message I've been getting whenever I compile is this: http://cache.gyazo.com/e56dddf2d0cd3f46dd7930fd64bbb684.png I think it has to do with my casting as an int the value in the arraylist which happens twice I believe in the class. I believe it has to do with that because I'm getting the same thing in another class of mien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `war()` method you are recursively calling `war()` and `war()` will eventually end by recalling `play()`. So there will be multiple instances executing `play()`. Eventually when the cards run out for one player all this instances will comeback as the stack is unwound and continue executing `play()`. And finally of course calling `victory()` and printing it multiple times (should be the amount of times `war()` was called).

So each war() may print out a player has won once it reached the bottom of the recursion. I don't think the call to `play()` in `war()` is necessary, it will go back to the `play()` method after it finishes the `war()` method anyway.

Comment: could you clarify at what point the recursion causes the message to print multiple times? Because war() is only called recursively if victory has not occurred, and if it has, then it isn't called recursively again. Besides, calling war() doesn't print out anything. war() doesn't call the victory() method.

Comment: war() can call play() which intern will eventually call victory. So basically every time a war is started eventually it will call play() again, that should not happen.

Comment: @viggom555 remember to respond to my answer. Is this indeed the case, if not leave a comment? If correct, please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Yup, I just checked this website for the first time in a few days. Your answer was very helpful. Thanks!